# Remove words from array of string

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, array.prototype.map

I have an array of strings:

```
[
  'Alica Brereton,Marijuana,9.18,50',
  'David Ernest,Methamphetamine,108.78,5',
  'David Ernest,cocaine,80,2',
  'Gabriella Hyde,Marijuana,9.18,10',
  'Gabriella Hyde,Methamphetamine,108.78,8',
  'Joel Forro,ecstasy,19.12,10',
  'Joel Forro,heroin,91.16,5',
  'William Kotai,ecstasy,19.12,20'
]
```

and i would like to remove the names from the start of each string so the end result would be:

[
'Marijuana,9.18,50',
'Methamphetamine,108.78,5',
'cocaine,80,2',
'Marijuana,9.18,10',
'Methamphetamine,108.78,8',
'19.12,10',
'heroin,91.16,5',
'ecstasy,19.12,20'
]

this is my existing code:

```
const fs = require("fs");
const data = fs.readFileSync("data.txt").toString();
const lines = data.split("\n");

let customerKeys = lines[0].replace("customer", "Total Price");
lines.shift();
console.log(customerKeys);
console.log(lines);

let array = lines.filter((str) => {
  return str !== "";
});
let arrNoSpaces = array;

arrNoSpaces.sort();
console.log(arrNoSpaces);

let keyValues = (customerKeys[0] += arrNoSpaces[1]);
keyValues += {};
console.log(keyValues);

customerKeys = customerKeys.split(",");
var TotalPrice = customerKeys.shift();
customerKeys.push(TotalPrice);


const customerNames = arrNoSpaces.map((line) => line.match(/\w+ \w+/)?.[0]);
```

Comment: Please add the code you've attempted to your question as a [mcve]. You clearly know that `map` (or a loop) is involved somewhere.

Comment: `data.map(v => v.replace(/^[^,]*,/, ''))`

Comment: Arithmetic Progression - remove elements that come at 3nth place starting 0 0, 3, 6 until the length of the array exhausts.

Comment: This looks like the list of my high school's valedictorians.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o14wj5ev/